# Send single document to multiple mail id's using docusign rest api

Tags: php, docusignapi

```
$data = array(
             "emailSubject" => "DocuSign API - Signature Request on Document",
            "documents" => array( array( "documentId" => "1", "name" => $documentName)),
            "recipients" => array( "signers" => array(
                array(  "email" => "XXX@gmail.com",
                        "name" => "XXX",
                        "recipientId" => "1",
                        "tabs" => array(
                            "signHereTabs" => array(
                                array( "xPosition" => "500",
                                       "yPosition" => "500",
                                       "documentId" => "1",
                                       "pageNumber" => "1" )
                            ))
                 ))
            ),
        "status" => "sent"
    );
```

I use above code for single mail id, and its work but i want to use multiple email id for one template

Comment: You want more people to sign?

Comment: Yes, I have 3 email id and send one document to all 3

Comment: You should add a new array to the signers, just a copy of the array that is already there.

Comment: It works, Thank you for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signers node is an array so just add another signer object to the array, for instance here's the corresponding JSON for sending to 2 different recipients and assigning one signature tab per signer:

```
{
    "emailSubject": "Please sign this document...",
    "emailBlurb": "Sent from the DocuSign API",
    "status": "sent",
    "documents": [{
        "documentId": "1",
        "name": "test.pdf"
    }],
    "recipients": {
        "signers": [{
            "email": "sallydoe@email.com",
            "name": "Sally Doe",
            "recipientId": "1",
            "tabs": {
                "signHereTabs": [{
                    "xPosition": "100",
                    "yPosition": "200",
                    "documentId": "1",
                    "pageNumber": "1"
                }]
            }
        }, {
            "email": "johndoe@email.com",
            "name": "John Doe",
            "recipientId": "2",
            "tabs": {
                "signHereTabs": [{
                    "xPosition": "100",
                    "yPosition": "300",
                    "documentId": "1",
                    "pageNumber": "1"
                }]
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply but i have one another question if you can help?
I want to send my own pdf for signature using embedded docusign rest api, My embedded docusign code is working well using template id.

Comment: You should post that as a separate question.